# Why didn't Dave Lister go home?

Tags: red-dwarf

If I recall correctly, in the early series of Red Dwarf, Dave Lister's ambition was to find a way back to Earth, and go home. But in the Series 7 episode Ouroboros, he uses a time drive to do just that - it teleports him back to Earth in the late 22nd Century, where he leaves his baby self under a pool table in a club in Liverpool. Why didn't he then just time-jump forward a few years and stay on Earth?

Out of universe, that would have meant the end of the series for good, but was there ever an in-universe reason given?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is explained in the episode;

> **LISTER:** *For a long time, you'll think that you were abandoned, but you weren't, man.  You were put here to create a paradox, an
>   unbreakable circle.  **With us going 'round and 'round in time, the
>   human race can never become extinct.** We're like... a kind of
>   'holding pattern'.*

Dave Lister is well aware that he may be the last human in existence. His goal is to get back to Earth in the present and **continue the human race**, preferably by having lots of babies with Kochanski.

If he stays on Earth in the past then the human race becomes instantly extinct in the future, and worse, he'll have been *personally responsible* for that happening.

Comment: When Lister says "a kind of 'holding pattern'", a holding pattern is "the flight path maintained by an aircraft awaiting permission to land" - what does this metaphor mean?

Comment: @Jimmery it means exactly that. If you are in a holding pattern you are waiting for the next event to occur.

Comment: "If he stays on Earth in the past then the human race becomes instantly extinct in the future" - no, because he wouldn't be *replacing* his other self. He'd be an additional Lister happy to end his days on Earth in the same way he'd end them on a spaceship. Provided he didn't screw up the timeline butterfly-effect style in some other way, there's no reason he couldn't have remained.

Comment: @moopet The human race would be extinct in the future beyond the point Lister left. From the point of view of a local observer, the last human would have vanished at the point he traveled back in time.

Comment: @IMSoP why? He's left himself there as a baby. That baby through to that adult are the "holding pattern". What he does with his life after that is irrelevant.

Comment: @moopet If the adult Lister steps into a time machine in the year 6000123, and stays in the past, and never comes back, then there is no Lister in the year 6000124. Granted, at some point he'd die of old age anyway, say in the year 6000170, but he's at least delaying the extinction by continuing to live in the years in between.

Comment: delaying the extinction of the human race doesn't make much odds by a few years though. If he died of old age in 6000133 he'd have been "personally responsible" in the same way, and since (by definition) nobody else would be around to know about it, does it really matter?

Comment: @moopet - It evidently matters to him

Comment: Plus, he will eventually sire two children, Jim and Bexley, (both named after his favorite sports star, Jim Bexley Speed) so he can't leave before that.